# How to provide from dependency imongocollection c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I want to get IMongoCollection from constructor, like dbContext. Which kind of dependency injection I should to use?

*Database context DI:*

```
   services.AddScoped<DbContext>();
```

*Provider context class:*

```
    public Provider(
        DbContext context,
        IMongoCollection<Entity> collection)
    {
        _context = context;
        _collection = context.EntitiesCollection;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Registered  BooksService class with DI to support constructor injection in consuming classes.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.Configure<BookStoreDatabaseSettings>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("BookStoreDatabase"));

builder.Services.AddSingleton<BooksService>();
```

The BooksService class uses the following MongoDB.Driver members to run CRUD operations against the database:

```
public BooksService(
    IOptions<BookStoreDatabaseSettings> bookStoreDatabaseSettings)
{
    var mongoClient = new MongoClient(
        bookStoreDatabaseSettings.Value.ConnectionString);

    var mongoDatabase = mongoClient.GetDatabase(
        bookStoreDatabaseSettings.Value.DatabaseName);

    _booksCollection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<Book>(
        bookStoreDatabaseSettings.Value.BooksCollectionName);
}
```

Read [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) to know more.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for generic classes :

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IMongoDb<>), typeof(MongoDbContext<>));
```

using :

```
    private readonly IMongoDb<Entity> _db;
    private readonly IMongoCollection<Entity> _mongoCollection;
    public SaveService(IMongoDb<Entity> db)
    {
        _db = db;
        _mongoCollection = _db.GetCollection();
    }
```